# How to return the last day of each month

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a view where i have multiple records showing up for each month. 
Example: January is showing 20 records and February is showing 30 records. I only want the last record of EACH MONTH to show up. So i want to see 1 record for each month.

I have already tried the first() and last() table calculation, but it does not filter by month, but by column.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

1 Calculated Field - DateMonth

```
 Datetrunc('month',Date)
```

2 Calculative field - LastDate

```
{ FIXED DateMonth: max(Date)}
```

3 Calculative Field- Filter

```
if lastDate=Date then 'Yes' else 'No' end
```

Comment: this did not work. Maybe you can give more context to where each calculated needs to go (Row, Column, Mark, Filter)? i added the first 2 as rows and then the last one as a filter and it did not work properly @Vishal Gupta

Comment: @Ezzy you just need to put Filter as a filter and set it to yes. Don't need to put anything in row

Answer (score 0):

If you just apply first and last on the dataaset then you won't get the correct output, If you need for every month then you need to divide the partition to year and month and then apply the max on the specific partition.

Try this way:

Place the order date in `Exact date` format and change the property to `discrete`

Now extract the year and month in separate calculated fields and place in detail.

Year:

```
year(Date)
```

Month:

```
Month(date)
```

Now create one more calculated field and write below code:

```
WINDOW_MAX(MAX([Order Date]),FIRST(),LAST())
```

[image]

Comment: this did not work. Maybe you can give more context to where each calculated needs to go (Row, Column, Mark, Filter)?